# Difference between FutureTask and AsyncTask in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask, futuretask

I want to know the difference between `FutureTask` and `AsyncTask` in android. According to my thinking we can get the current situation in FutureTask. Using `ExecutorService` we can create a pool of parallel processes. Same property we can achieve using AsyncTask . I want to know the situation where to use AsyncTask and when to use FutureTask.

I have asked a **Question** [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951034/asynctask-doesnt-call-on-applying-space-to-a-url?noredirect=1#comment38780986_24951034) but not getting any response . Now i think i should change my way of getting webservices data. So i think i should use `FutureTask` because they have function like isDone()

and cancel. Please some one guide me any better way to retrieve data from web-services. because my textView set's the adapter too slow.

Or simply i need a way to cancel the running AsyncTasks or replace it with the current. When user press `w` it call for the AsyncTask and when he added any word to it in AutotextView it will call thrice for `waka` one for `wa` and `wak` and one for `waka` . Is it possible to cancel the running task when user presses another text.  See my [**Question here for Details**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24951034/asynctask-doesnt-call-on-applying-space-to-a-url).

Comment: Well they are as different as a river bank is to a capacitor bank. Two different classes whose purpose you could probably have worked out just by reading the docs: [FutureTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html), [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Comment: I read both docs and still don't have a good idea when to use which. It seems I could always use a future task....

Comment: @813951 "Read the docs" is an insult, not an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`AsyncTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) provides callbacks (`onPreExecute`, `onProgressExecute`, and `onPostExecute`) which are guaranteed to run on the UI thread. **AsyncTask is deprecated** (thanks [chokdee](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2086219/chokdee)).

[`FutureTask`](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/concurrent/FutureTask.html) provides no callbacks and doesn't know anything about the Android UI thread. In fact, Android apps shouldn't call `Future.get()` from the UI thread, because it may block.

Android apps should use [Kotlin coroutines](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/coroutines). If you're stuck in Java, use `FutureTask`.

Comment: Since API Level 30 AsyncTask is deprecated and FutureTask or Executor should be used

Answer (score 0):

**Exception Handling:**

if exception throw in AsyncTask.doInBackground, then this exception will rethrow as RuntimeException in AsyncTask threadpool thread(not UI thread commonly)

if exception throw in FutureTask.run, then this exception will be catched by FutureTask and rethrow when you call FutureTask.get()

**isCancelled() invocation**

in FutureTask.run can't invoke FutureTask.isCancelled(), but in AsyncTask.doInBackground can invoke AsyncTask.isCancelled()